# jquery convert number into string in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a form for printing cheques. I need when I enter amount in numeric format in a input field there should be auto fill that particular number in string format in a another field.here is the form,it's very simple form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <p id="namecont">name: <input type="text" id="name"/></p> 
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
    <p>Amount: <input type="text" id="amount" /></p>
    <p>Amount in Letters: <input type="text" id="amount_string" /></p>

</form>
```

Comment: see [this](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/05/convert-numbers-to-words.html), it may help you. Actually you should do some try first and then come to SO.

Comment: use just plain javascript String("your number here")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to convert from string to number since they will all be processed as strings. But here it goes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#amount").keyup(function () {
        $("#amount_string").val(Number($("#amount").val()).toString());
    });
});
```

Edit: Read your question wrong. You would use this handler and then combine that with kiruthiga's answer to produce your desired result.